# Template Class that takes a Template Class that Takes a Concrete Class

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

While I've seen a few posts regarding taking in template classes as a parameter into a template class I can't seem to find something that works with my code, or simply I do not understand the explanation well enough.

Ultimately, I'm looking for a template class that takes another template class which takes a standard class.

*Note: For brevity, I've only included what I believe to be sufficient information.

I've made an attempt based on the information I could find and it is shown here:

Concrete Class

```
class ConcreteClass {
   private:
      std::string words;
   public:
      ConcreteClass(std::string newWords);
};
#endif
```

Template Class template

```
template <class ConcreteClass>
class TemplateClass{
   private:
     ConcreteClass stuff;
   public:
     TemplateClass(ConcreteClass fillStuff);
};

#endif


template <class ConcreteClass>
TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>::TemplateClass(ConcreteClass fillStuff) {
     stuff = fillStuff;
}
```

Base Class template

```
template<template<class> ConcreteClass, class TemplateClass>
class BaseClass {
   private:
     TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>* objPntr;
}

template<template<class> ConcreteClass, class TemplateClass>
BaseClass<TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>::BaseClass(TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>* newObj) {
    objPntr = newObj;
}
template<template<class> ConcreteClass, class TemplateClass>
BaseClass<TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>::~BaseClass() {
   if(objPntr) {
      delete objPntr;
    }
}
```

Main

```
int main() {
   ConcreteClass cClass("some values");
   TemplateClass tClass(cClass);
   BaseClass(tClass);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I apologize. I realized that I did not give sufficient enough code to represent my issue or intentions, I will update it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need a `class` or `typename` keyword before the template parameter name in the case of template-templates. Secondly, you should put the `template<class>` before `TemplateClass`, not `ConcreteClass`. `TemplateClass` **is** your templated type, so it needs that specifier:

```cpp
#include <string>

// I had to make up your types because there is no definition for them
struct ConcreteClass {
    std::string value;
};

template <typename T>
struct TemplateClass {
    T t;
};

template<class ConcreteClass, template<class> class TemplateClass>
class BaseClass {
   private:
     TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>* objPntr;

// constructor needs to be declared before being defined
public:
     BaseClass(TemplateClass<ConcreteClass> *objPntr);
};

template<class ConcreteClass, template<class> class TemplateClass>
BaseClass<ConcreteClass, TemplateClass>::BaseClass(TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>* newObj) {
    objPntr = newObj;
}

int main() {
   ConcreteClass cClass{"some values"};
   TemplateClass<ConcreteClass> tClass{cClass};
   BaseClass<ConcreteClass, TemplateClass> bClass(&tClass);
}
```

Comment: getting an compiler error stating: BaseClass<TemplateClass<ConcreteClass>>:: has too few arguments as well as got 1 expected 2. Also another error that says conflicting template declaration.

Comment: This solution was edited prior to me adding more code to provide more context to my situation. The solution does solve my issue.